# How can I mark the instance of String class?

Tags: java, string

I need to create the class which should have the possibility to mark String and check it:

```
public class Checker {
    
    public static void markFlag(String flag) {
    }
    
    public static boolean isFlagMarked(String flag) {
    }
}
```

For example:

```
Checker.markFlag("a");

Checker.isFlagMarked("a"); // true

Checker.isFlagMarked("b"); // false

Checker.isFlagMarked("c"); // false
```

I know that String class has a private boolean field `isHashZero` which is `false` till we don't call `hashcode()` method, and it's a really cool marker, but I am not allowed to use Reflection API.

Also, I think I can create `HashSet markedFlags` in the Checker class and just add the marked flags to it. But it requires a lot of memory I guess. Can you help me find the best solution? Will be thankful for any advice.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what `markFlag()` and `isFlagMarked()` are supposed to do?  Are you essentially saying "I've seen this string before"?  What would the result be if you passed in string "Something with a in it" to `isFlagMarked()` after you had marked "a"?

Comment: "I am not allowed to use Reflection": Sounds like either homework or a job interview. What have you tried? What about it didn't work? See [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166).

Comment: About the memory issue: if you can afford some level of error, you can also use a [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).

Comment: @guz `Checker.isFlagMarked()` returns true if `Checker.markFlag()` has been called for a given String.

Comment: @MikaelF intresting, thank you

Comment: Is it a requirement to use static methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep a set of the strings. If this will be called from different threads, use a thread-safe collection.

Anything do with fiddling the internals of a String instance is destined for failure: distinct instances can represent the same value, the internals of the class might be changed in future releases etc.

```
public class Checker {
    private static final Set<String> markedFlags = new HashSet<>();
    
    public static void markFlag(String flag) {
        markedFlags.add(flag);
    }

    public static boolean isFlagMarked(String flag) {
        return markedFlags.contains(flag);
    }
}
```

> But it requires a lot of memory I guess.

No it doesn't. The strings already exist in your application. The only memory is an array big enough to hold the references. So ~ `32 or 64bits * number of marked strings`, i.e. irrelevant